# How can I find vapour properties of a compound molten salt?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, vapor-pressure, salt

I'm carrying out thermal-hydraulic simulations of the [Aircraft Reactor Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Reactor_Experiment) (a nuclear molten salt reactor) based on circulating **molten fuel salt**: NaF 53 mol%, ZrF4 41 mol%, UF4 6 mol%.

While the **liquid** salt thermodynamic **properties** have been measured and are hence **available**, the properties at **saturation** and the properties of the **vapour** phase are **unknown**. Due to numerical needs, I now need to switch from a *pure liquid* simulation to a "fake" *liquid + vapour* simulation ("fake" as the operating conditions should be well below the saturation temperature).

Hence, I need to introduce sensible (but not necessarily precise) thermodynamic properties for the vapour phase, as well, so that the **simulation** effectively remains in **pure liquid**.

I have all the **liquid** laws needed, for the following properties:

- specific enthalpy $h_l(p,T) = (34.5 + 0.235 \times (T-273.15) )\times4184.$
- density $\rho_l(p,T) = ((3.98 - 0.00093(T-273.15))\times1000.)\times\exp(10^{-9}p)$
- specific isobaric heat capacity $c_{p,l}(p,h)$ (simply $=\dfrac{\partial h_l}{\partial T}$)
- thermal conductivity, dynamic viscosity.

Now, similarly, for the **vapour** phase I need:

- specific enthalpy $h_v(p,T)$
- density $\rho_v(p,T)$
- specific isobaric heat capacity $c_{p,v}(P)$ (which however could also be taken as the derivative of the enthalpy?)
- [thermal conductivity and dynamic viscosity, but these are less relevant for the simulation]

Whereas at **saturation** I need the following:

- pressure at saturation temperature $P(T_{sat})$
- temperature at saturation pressure $T(P_{sat})$
- liquid and vapour specific enthalpies at saturation pressure $h_{l,sat}(P_{sat})$, $h_{v,sat}(P_{sat})$
- similarly, liquid and vapour densities and isobaric heat capacities $\rho_l(P_{sat})$, $\rho_v(P_{sat})$, $c_{p,l}(P_{sat})$, $c_{p,v}(P_{sat})$

Since reasonably, we should be able to deduce the properties at saturation from the properties of the two phases, this makes the vapour properties the real goal.

I've started looking [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) for the vapour laws. For instance, I've found properties for a single component of the salt like NaF [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C7681494&Mask=1#Thermo-Gas), but I am unsure whether the properties of single molecules suit the compound salt.

So, finally: what should I do?

Comment: Sadly, having glanced through a number of papers modeling molten salt binary/ternary/higher order phase diagrams (often mentioning various experiments as motivation), I find no gas phase data available in them. And it would appear that there are gas phase reactions, making modeling of the gas phase trickier than one might normally expect.